# Stop presenting PushNotification

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I don't want to present a notification when I don't get `userId` in notification's `userInfo`.

So how can I stop notification to present?

Code I tried:

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("willPresent notification")

        let aps = notification.request.content.userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")]!
        guard let data = aps as? [String: Any] else{ return}

        if let userId = data["userId"] as? String {
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }else{
            return
        }
    }
```

but still notification is presented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this

```
if let userId = data["userId"] as? String {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
} else {
       completionHandler([])
}
```

Comment: Yupp... Perfect!

Comment: nyc trick, but be aware, S.O. team might suspend your and buddys  account. @ktr kathir